# Loading required data from cassandra using pig

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I have a doubt with pig/cassandra load.

Am using pig to load data from cassandra using CqlStorage. like this

```
data = LOAD 'cq://ks/cf' using CqlStorage();
```

i want to load only few data by filtering, the column that i want to filter are partition keys and there is bug in this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6151) so i cannot do this.

so planning to filter with pig, `b = filter data by col1 == 'something';`

**My doubt is, whether pig loads all the data from cassandra and then filter? or will it send filter condition to CqlStorage to load only required data from cassandra.?**